# StructureMap injection question

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am trying to use StructureMap and have essentially 3 levels of abstraction.  I have a service a repository and database interface.  So the IService depends on IRepo and IRepo depends on IDatabase.  My issue is that my IDatabase concrete type takes in db connection information. I am going to create these on the fly, trying to use ObjectFactory.Configure().

So I have a user and the user is linked to a company and the I lookup the company connection information and I want to create the proper IDatabase concrete type based on this information.  I have the concrete type configured in my startup code. I only want to use the IService object from outside...so I want to create a named IService object named with the company Name.  Having issues with trying to create these types on the fly.  ANY information would be helpfull...

I basically want to be able to create a named instance and either set properties or pass specific args to a constructor at runtime, without knowing the concrete type.  I have the concrete type setup in the config file.  I have tried to use the ObjectFactory.GetInstance and tried to set properties inside the Configure method, but got StackOverflow exception...HOW IRONIC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer with direction from Jeremy Miller (author of StructureMap).  Here is where he pointed me to:

http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/RetrievingServices.htm#section5

here is an example of what I used:

```
IDatabaseRepository repo =
                ObjectFactory.With("server").EqualTo("servername").
                With("database").EqualTo("dbName").
                With("user").EqualTo("userName").
                With("password").EqualTo("password").
                GetInstance<IDatabaseRepository>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like Structuremap's ObjectFactory supports injecting named instances